# Error in Expression used for Control Source in an Access Form

Tags: ms-access

I actually have two questions.

I'm a beginner user of Access, still trying to get a good understanding of the software. I'm trying to create a database for a library (School project) with a borrowing out system. I have two fields in a table called DueDate and DateHired. The DueDate functions on the expression =Now()+28 and the DateHired function on the expression =Now(). Basically making the due date 4 weeks ahead of when the book was hired. My first question is quite simple; if I were to input a record today, would the two DueDate/DateHired fields remain the same date and time by tomorrow? Or would they update to the Now() of tomorrow?

My second question is something regarding an expression. I'm trying to make an Overdue checkbox. The premise is that if Now()>DateDue then the Checkbox will be 'Yes'. My current code in the ControlSource part is this:

=CBool([DateDue]

However, the checkbox simply displays '#Error' and not Yes/No. I'm also concerned that if the answer to the first question was '=Now() stays the same after the record is added and doesn't update' that would also mean the Overdue function would not really work unless you were inputting the record after the due date. Which would make no sense. Any suggestions?

Cheers.

Comment: Please target one specific question, or ask 2 different questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is relation to your second question. You can ask a separate question for the first part.

```
=CBool([DateDue]
```

What you are trying to do here, is convert a `Date` data type to a `Boolean` (you're missing the closing parentheses by the way) which is impossible.

What you should be doing is check if the due date is less than today and return the appropriate `True/False` value.

```
IIf([DueDate] < Date(), True, False)
```

Which means:

```
IIf("Is due date in the past?", "Yes, it's overdue", "No, it's not overdue")
```

---

You can read more about the `IIf` function [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as a beginner, make it a habit to use the date functions. Later you can turn to "smarter" methods which, by the way, often aren't that smart.

**1.**

If you store a date, it remains unchanged in the table. And don't use Now unless you specifically need the hours too:

```
DateDue = DateAdd("d", 28, DateHired)
```

or in a query - using the designer:

```
DateDue: DateAdd("d",28,[DateHired])
```

or as a ControlSource for a textbox on your form:

```
=DateAdd("d",28,[DateHired])
```

**2.**

You can use *DateDiff* for this:

```
Due = DateDiff("d", DateHired, Date) > 28
```

or in a query - using the designer:

```
Due: DateDiff("d",[DateHired],Date()) > 28
```

or as a ControlSource for a textbox on your form:

```
=DateDiff("d",[DateHired],Date()) > 28
```

and set the *Format* property of the textbox to, say, *Yes/No* or something else meaningful for your users.